# virtual box doesnt shows 64 bit os in ubuntu14.04 64 bit

Tags: virtualbox, 14.04

I installed 64 bit Ubuntu 14.04 in my home PC and Virtual Box in it. But the real problem is V box only shows 32 bit OSes. I had a same problem in 12.04 also(and i didn't got a solution!). Is there any solution for that? I really need to install 64 bit windows as a VM. I use V Box version 4.3.10.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a X86-64 based guest operating system you must have a X86-64 host cpu with virtualization support (eg Intel VT-x and AMD-V). Virtualization support obviously must be turned on in order to use it. This is done in your BIOS or UEFI.

Sources:

http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#hwvirt

Comment: I've intel core2duo processor

Comment: @RajeshRajendran: not all Core2 Duo processors suppor VT-x: http://ark.intel.com/products/virtualizationtechnology

Comment: I googled the specs of intel core2duo e4500,unfortunately which is mine, doesn't really support vtx!!! so is there any other option?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem once

try to use VMware Player and load you 64 bit vm